# How to reset password on Kyocera FS-1128MFP

Tags: printing

I'm trying to configure a kyocera fs-1128MFP, but i dont have the adminstrator password.

Is there anyway to reset the machine to factory defaults.

Comment: Have you tried the Kyocera web site, or perhaps the user manual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the Web login password is admin00.
The login from the control panel is UN: 2800   PW: 2800

Comment: This saved the printer from an early grave - why on earth are the credentials different on the control panel to the web admin interface Kyocera???

Answer (score 3):

You could try the default admin password - admin00